# android:nextFocusForward is ignored in layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an android xml layout and i want to specify the focus order of the fields, when user presses next on the keyboard.

Documentation says, that **android:nextFocusForward=TARGET_ID** should do that trick. But it is ignored on all our testing devices. Some old devices running 2.3 and new Nexus devices running 4.1.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
            android:id="@+id/firstname"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:nextFocusForward="@+id/lastname"
            android:padding="2dp"/>

        <EditText
            android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
            android:id="@+id/lastname"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:padding="2dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

What am i doing wrong here??? Just can't figure it out. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try nextFocusDown as well. I don't fully understand the rules, but it seems that the behavior depends on the layout of the EditTexts, and where the cursor position is relative to the next field.

Answer (score 1):

I tried setting nextFocusDown, nextFocusForward, nextFocusRight, but none of them worked. I got it working by listening for editor action and programmatically setting the focus to the next EditText.

```
    mFirstName.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            mLastName.requestFocus();
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Another variant of this: `mFirstName.focusSearch(View.FOCUS_DOWN).requestFocus()`

Answer (score 1):

It's been a long time, but I just had the problem and found the solution. nextFocusForward works when AutoCompleteTextView is overwritten with imeOptions.
I have this code in my EditText fields and it works:

```
android:imeOptions="actionNext"
android:nextFocusForward="@+id/et_xyz"
```

Comment: Setting both properties solves the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue within toolbar/actionbar with JetPack. I seems toolbar widget totally ignores the nextFocus properties. I solved it by not using those legacy widgets and using a custom toolbar base on standard widgets.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue where I had text fields in a grid with two columns and several rows defined and arranged using the `ConstraintLayout` and `Flow`.

```
android:nextFocusDown="@id/..."
```

Worked for me in all text fields regardless of the next view being on the right.